# What does Johnny Cash refer to when he says he has a “mackinaw?”

Tags: lyrics, meaning, country

In Johnny Cash’s song *Country Trash*, he says:

> I got a mackinaw and a hunting dog

What is a mackinaw? I’m a Michigander myself, so I’m familiar with Mackinac Island and Mackinaw City and the etymology of those names, I’m just unclear as to what a mackinaw is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it is a raincoat.

> Mackinaw cloth is a heavy dense water-repellent woolen cloth, similar to Melton cloth. It was used to make a short coat of the same name, sometimes with a doubled shoulder. These jackets have their origins on the Canadian frontier and were later made famous by American loggers in the upper Midwest as workwear during the mid-19th century logging boom.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mackinaw_cloth

[image]

http://cdn-5.olive-drab.com/images/soldier_ww2_field_unif_01.jpg

Comment: Upper Midwest, hence “mackinaw.” Thanks!